# Error when I try to add styles with jquery

Tags: jquery

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

When I run this code:

```
$('.field table[border!="0"] td').css({
border: 1px solid black,
color: red
});
```

I can't see what the error is.

UPDATE:

```
$('.field table[border!="0"] td').css({
border-width: '1px',
border-style: 'solid'
});
```

the error is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enclose values in quotes

```
$('.field table[border!="0"] td').css({
'border': '1px solid black',
'color': 'red'
});
```

Comment: damnit, people here are so frikkin fast to answer questions. But great answer ;)

Comment: your code works. but mine not. I will paste the last code I used at the bottom of my question

Comment: Try enclosing properties in quotes as well.